# Linear Algebra 101 - Optimizing inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I am considering the region contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of all the points that satisfy all the following inequality:

$-4 \leq y < 4 \\
-9 \leq 2x + y \leq 9 \\
-9 \leq x + 2y \leq 9 \\
-4 \leq x < 4 \\
-9 \leq 2x - y \leq 9  \\
-9 \leq x - 2y \leq 9 $

Determine the maximum value of $f(x,y)= 5x +10y + \pi^2$ on this region. At which points in the region does it occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\pi^2$ is a constant, your problem is really maximizing $g(x,y)=5x+10y$, subject to the linear inequalities you're listing.

The solution is **not** strictly inside the region. It will actually be one of the "corner points" that define the polytope induced by the inequalities. Look up [the fundamental theorem of linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_programming).

Now, since you have positive coefficients in your objective function, you only need to investigate the corner points that occur in the first quadrant ($x \ge 0, y \ge 0$); any other feasible solution that lists either $x$ or $y$ as negative is dominated by one with positive values, since it increases your goal.

In the first quadrant there are three such points:

$A$, at the intersection of $y=4$ with $x+2y = 9$. It therefore has coordinates $(1,4)$.

$B$, at the intersection of $x+2y=9$ with $2x+y=9$. Solving simultaneously you get the coordinates $(3,3)$.

$C$, at the intersection of $2x+y=9$ with $x=4$. It therefore has coordinates $(4,1)$.

The value of your objective function are, for each of these points,
$$
f(1,4) = 5(1) + 10(4) + \pi^2 = 45 + \pi^2 \\
f(3,3) = 5(3) + 10(3) + \pi^2 = 45 + \pi^2 \\
f(4,1) = 5(4) + 10(1) + \pi^2 = 30 + \pi^2
$$

Since you get equal (maximum) values for points $A$ and $B$ you have alternate optimal solutions. The entire segment between $(4,1)$ and $(3,3)$ consists of optimal points.

Comment: so how would i go about solving it? would i solve for x and y?

Comment: Yes, exactly right. You'll solve a system of two equations in two unknowns formed by setting the line equations simultaneously equal. As a final hint, your feasible region is a dodecagon, so you'll have to examine at most 12 points. However, since your objective function coefficients are both positive, you can only focus on the first quadrant, thus looking at only 3 points (e.g. one such point is the intersection of $y=4$ with $2x+y \le 9$.

Comment: how do i find the max value? I have drawn it out, but am unable to find max?? Please help as I've been growing bald trying to figure this out!!!

Comment: @help: see my edited answer. Hope this clears things up.